# Gather data, count, and return list of dictionary even when data does not exists

Tags: python, mysql, count

Let's say I have a mysql table like this.

```
| id | type        | sub_type | customer    |
|  1 | animal      | cat      | John        |
|  2 | animal      | dog      | Marry       |
|  3 | animal      | fish     | Marry       |
|  3 | animal      | bird     | John        |
```

What I have to do is gather data by customer and count rows by sub_type. The animal type has 4 sub_types (`cat`, `dog`, `fish`, `bird`) and John has two sub_types(`cat`, `bird`) and `Marry` also has two sub_types(`dog`, `fish`). Let's say I want to get a result of `John`, It should look like this.

```
[
  {name='cat', count=1},
  {name='dog', count=0},
  {name='fish', count=0},
  {name='bird', count=1}
]
```

When I want to get a result about `Marry`, It should look like this.

```
[
  {name='cat', count=0},
  {name='dog', count=1},
  {name='fish', count=1},
  {name='bird', count=0}
]
```

So, the sub_type that is not in database should be return with `count` of 0. Let's say I want to get result of `Matthew`. Since there is not data of `Matthew`, the result should look like this.

```
 [
  {name='cat', count=0},
  {name='dog', count=0},
  {name='fish', count=0},
  {name='bird', count=0}
]
```

I usually used `setdefault()` to make a result. My code probably look like this.

```
tmp = dict()
for row in queryset:
   tmp.setdefault(row.customer, dict(cat=0, dog=0, fish=0, bird=0))
   if row.sub_type == 'cat':
      tmp[row.customer][row.sub_type] += 1
```

However, I want to know if there is other way or more elegant way to do this.

Comment: Would you mind using `pandas`?

Comment: The answer likely depends on the `mysql` table type, so I added that tag to your question—it's not about using generic Python.

Comment: Yeah, I'd be tempted to use a query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you have a table named 'people' that contains the field 'name' that has the entries

```
name
--------
John
Mary
Mathew
```

and the table mentioned above is a table called 'pets'

You can use the following query to build your result-set for each person

```
select
  A.name as customer,
  (select count(*) from pets where customer=A.name and sub_type='cat') as cat,
  (select count(*) from pets where customer=A.name and sub_type='dog') as dog,
  (select count(*) from pets where customer=A.name and sub_type='fish') as fish,
  (select count(*) from pets where customer=A.name and sub_type='bird') as bird
from people A
```

with the result listed below

```
customer    cat     dog     fish    bird
John        1       0       0       1
Marry       0       1       1       0
Mathew      0       0       0       0
```

Add an additional where clause and filter my name or provide the
summary result for all at once.